# How can I take a incremental backup using mysqlbackup without removing the incremental directory?

Tags: mysql, mysql-backup

My idea is to create a cronjob to get a incremental backup of my database every half an hour or so.

According to `mysqlbackup` documentation I have to first take a full    backup of my database and then just take the incrementals later so I    did this:

```
mysqlbackup --defaults-file=.my.cnf --compress \
   --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --no-locking \
   --compress-level=9 --databases=employees \
   --show-progress=stdout --backup-dir=/home/user/backup backup
```

Then I go into my backups directory and create a incrementals       directory, then I run this following command to get the incrementals:

```
mysqlbackup --defaults-file=.my.cnf --incremental --no-locking \
  --databases=employees --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock \
  --incremental-base=dir:backup/ \
  --incremental-backup-dir=backup/incrementals/ \
  backup
```

Everything looks as it's expected, then when I want to run it again, I get this error:

```
 mysqlbackup: ERROR: Backup directory already exists and is not empty.
 Remove backup directory and retry.
```

The main reason why I'm doing incrementals is so I don't have only one backup file so this is not an ideal scenario for me, specially because I don't want to create a cronjob that deletes the incremental directory every time I have to get a new incremental backup.

So my question is, **how can I create incremental backups every time I execute the command and creates a new file with whatever has changed in the database?**

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue and needed to add another option, --with-timestamp to create unique filenames in the backup directory.